# Verify PKCS 7 with key from file fails

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I have some Bouncy Castle code that verifies a PKCS 7 signatures:

```
        CMSSignedData s = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(toVerifyBytes), signedByte);

      Store                   certStore = s.getCertificates();
      SignerInformationStore  signers = s.getSignerInfos();
      Collection              c = signers.getSigners();
      Iterator                it = c.iterator();

      while (it.hasNext())
      {
          SignerInformation   signer = (SignerInformation)it.next();
          Collection          certCollection = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID());
          Iterator              certIt = certCollection.iterator();
          X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next();

          if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert)))
          {
              System.out.println("Verified OK");
          }   
      }
```

This works perfectly and signature is verified OK.

BUT - then I save the PKCS 7 signature element as a p7b file in Windows, opens it in Windows, and use Windows functionality to extract the two certificates to .cer-files and store on disk. I then write some code to load the pub keys from file instead of using the certificates directly from the signature.

The code looks like this:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\path\\pubkey.cer");

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificates(fis).iterator().next();
    fis.close();

    CMSSignedData s = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(toVerifyBytes), signedByte);
    SignerInformationStore signers = s.getSignerInfos();

    Collection c = signers.getSigners();
    Iterator it = c.iterator();

     while (it.hasNext())
      {
          System.out.println(cert.getPublicKey());

         SignerInformation   signerInfo = (SignerInformation)it.next();

          if (signerInfo.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert.getPublicKey())))
          {
              System.out.println("Verified OK");
          } else {
              System.out.println("NOT Veried OK");
          }
      }
```

This verification always fails. What can be the reason? Is the key export doing something? Am I using wrong object when loading from file?

If I print the certificate in code *(.toString())* the key shows as expected.

Comment: Two remarks: it looks like you check only with one certificate. That doesn't work if there is a certificate chain. Furthermore, it seems to me that you could as well give the entire certificate instead of just the public key.